# Invalid password while testing Devise

Tags: devise, capybara, factory-bot

I try to run test

```
describe "CreateFolders" do
  describe "GET /projects" do
    it "new folder", :js => true do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      visit projects_path
      fill_in('user_Login', :with => @user.email)
      fill_in('user_password', :with => @user.password)
      click_button('Sign in')
      page.should have_content('Logged in')
    end
  end
```

I see

```
Failures:

  1) CreateFolders GET /projects new folder
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content('Logged in')
       expected there to be content "Logged in" in "Invalid email or password.\nSign in\nRemember me\nForgot your password?"                                                                                                                     
     # ./spec/requests/create_folders_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

==============================================================================
UPDATED

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.free_email
    password 'password'
    Name Faker::Name.first_name
    Surname Faker::Name.last_name
    Phone Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
    Login Faker::Name.first_name
    company {|user| user.association(:company) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your factory definition for `:user`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use cucumber for this goal

```
  @javascript
  Scenario Outline: Show or not dasboard
    Given the following user records
      | email                | password  | login    |
      | admin@mail.com       | password  | admin    |

    When I am on the home page
    And I fill in "user_email" with "<login>"
    And I fill in "user_password" with "<password>"
    And I press "Sign in"
    Then I should <flash>

    Examples:
      | login          | password | flash                         |
      | admin@mail.com | password | see "Signed in successfully." |
```

Comment: What does cucumber have to do with anything. You can do this just fine in rspec.

Answer (score 2):

In rails, there are three data bases sets: development db, test db& production db,
you might be creating the new user in the development db, where it should be created in the test db, because while you do the test, test db will used.

Make sure that the new user is created in the test db.

If you just need to visit a page that requires authentication, without testing the sign in form, here is an easy way to do it in Capybara: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Capybara)

I hope this will help!

Comment: When I call User.all after factory I get record from db. Thank you for the link. But     `Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2012-01-17 13:52:11', `current_sign_in_at` = '2012-01-17 13:52:11', `last_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1', `current_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1', `sign_in_count` = 1, `updated_at` = '2012-01-17 13:52:11' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1` When I use      `user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Capybara for testing. Try changing `fill_in` to the label names rather than the field names. For example:

```
fill_in "Login", :with => @user.email
fill_in "Password", :with => @user.password
```

These may be different for your app - just substitute whatever your fields labels are actually called (whatever you see on your screen when you go to the projects_path). Also, no need for brackets.